# Importing a Wikipedia Table as a Dataset?

Tags: import, dataset, data-acquisition, web

I am trying to import [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_virtual_reality_headsets#Tethered_VR_(PC-based_and_PlayStation_VR)) from Wikipedia into Mathematica as a `Dataset`. The fields I'm interested are `Name`, `Release Date (Y-M-D)` (parsed as a Wolfram date entity), and `PPD`.

I tried

```
Import["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_virtual_reality_\
headsets#Tethered_VR_(PC-based_and_PlayStation_VR)", "Dataset"]
```

but get `The Import element "Dataset" is not present when importing as HTML.`

Per another post I also tried

```
Import["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_virtual_reality_\
headsets#Tethered_VR_(PC-based_and_PlayStation_VR)", "Data"]
```

but seemingly get a bunch of stuff imported other than just the table.

Comment: In a URL the `#` just tells the browser to scroll to that location. It doesn't actually mean just the thing displayed when you do. That's your fundamental issue. Secondly you'll probably want to write some stuff to parse it with `XMLElement` and `Cases`. It's not particularly tough, but it can be annoying. Should be no more than a 10 minute exercise, though. 3 if you're comfortable with this kind of thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some mental hemming and hawing, I decided it'd be good to have a proper answer about importing HTML tables using something other than the often buggy `"Data"` field.

So here's what I got. First something to pull all the `"table"` fields:

```
getHTMLTables[url_String?(StringStartsQ[URLParse[#]["Scheme"], "http"] &)] :=

    getHTMLTables[Import[url, {"HTML", "XMLObject"}]];
getHTMLTables[xml : _XMLElement | XMLObject[___][___]] :=

  Cases[xml, XMLElement["table", _, _], Infinity];
```

Then something to make a [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) from a given table:

```
xmlTableToDataset[tab_] :=
 Module[{headerRow, headers, data, rows},
  headerRow =
   FirstCase[tab[[3]], XMLElement["tr", __], None, Infinity];
  headers =
   Cases[
    headerRow, 
    d : XMLElement["th", _, _] :>
     StringTrim@
      StringJoin@Flatten@System`Convert`HTMLImportDump`SymbolicXML2Text[d],
    Infinity
    ];
  rows =
   Cases[tab, XMLElement["tr", _, _], Infinity];
  data =
   Map[
    Cases[#, 
      d : XMLElement["td", _, _] :>
       StringTrim@
        StringJoin@Flatten@System`Convert`HTMLImportDump`SymbolicXML2Text[d],
      Infinity
      ] &,
    rows
    ];
  Dataset@Map[
    AssociationThread[headers, #] &,
    Select[data, Length@# == Length@headers &]
    ]
  ]
```

Finally this:

```
tables = getHTMLTables[
   "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_virtual_reality_headsets"];

ds = xmlTableToDataset@tables[[3]]

ds // Keys // First // Normal

{"Name", "Release Date (Y-M-D)", "Positional tracking", "Display", \
"Resolution (per eye)", "PPD", "Aspect Ratio (per eye)", "Refresh rate", \
"Field of view", "Audio", "Connectivity", "Weight", "Price", "Platform", \
"Other"}

ds[[All, {"Name", "PPD"}]] // First // Normal

<|"Name" -> "Razer OSVR HDK 1.4[1]", "PPD" -> "9.6"|>
```

The data is pretty dirty, but that's to be expected for tabular data. Unfortunately there isn't likely to be a JSON dump of that, so there's nothing to be done.

Comment: This is cool! Thank you for contributing it.

Comment: @b3m2a1: This is a very useful code for web-based research.