# Converting HTML Tables derived from URL's on the Web to Datasets 211112 Revisited

Tags: dataset, web-access, html, url

In a previous question  [[211112]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211112/importing-a-wikipedia-table-as-a-dataset) that deals with importing data from a
Wikipedia table directly into a Dataset.

For the following data:

```
tables = getHTMLTables[  "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_virtual_reality_headsets"]
```

as given by b3m2a1 works like a charm.

However, using the function xmlTableToDataset[tab_] as given as an answer
in 211112, followed by its evocation as also given, fails for a different URL
containing 5 HTML generated tables.  This is the case
even though the 5 tables seem to be faithfully identified as XML table
objects containing a list of XML-Objects for input into the xmlTableToDataset function:

```
tables = 
getHTMLTables["http://earthwise.bgs.ac.uk/index.php/OR/14/008_Lithostratigraphical_units_used_by_BGS"];
ds = xmlTableToDataset@tables[[3]]
```

Mapping over the third seemingly should work since there is a 3rd table
on the URL and encapsulated in the tables list.

Unfortunately, it only produces a cryptic figure of a small box as a result of the
following:

```
ds2 = xmlTableToDataset@tables2
```

whereas the command:

```
ds2 // Keys // First // Normal
```

generates the error: {} has zero length and no first element

It seems that something in the xmlTableToDataset function needs generalizing.
However, I can't seem to isolate the offending code even though I suspect it
has to do with either the tab[[3]] construct or perhaps the Symbolic XML for the
header row in the new target table that may be more complicated than expected.

**How can this function be generalized to work without failure on the tables on the new
target URL or other HTML tables on other URL's?**

Learning how to manipulate XMLObjects
still remains beyond my grasp so examples that broaden my understanding would be
most appreciated as would any other approach in this instance.

NB.  Strickly speaking, the above URL is not on the Wikipedia site itself but is pointed to as
a reference standard in various discussions of geology.  The first part (tables[[1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211112/importing-a-wikipedia-table-as-a-dataset)]) of table
actually has no header info and only 1 row, so it can be ignored.

Comment: For simple tables in simple web pages this works quite well and is super simple `Import["http://earthwise.bgs.ac.uk/index.php/OR/14/008_Lithostratigraphical_units_used_by_BGS", "Data"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Wikipedia tables have `<th>` tags on the first row whereas this webpage uses `<td>` tags for the header line. For this reason, in the `xmlTableToDataset` function you need to replace

```
headers =
    Cases[
        headerRow, 
        d : XMLElement["th", _, _] :> (... etc ...),
        Infinity ];
```

with

```
headers =
    Cases[
        headerRow, 
        d : XMLElement["td", _, _] :> (... etc ...),
        Infinity ];
```

Then we have small problem when reading the rows because the header line would be repeated. This can be solved by replacing:

```
rows = Cases[tab, XMLElement["tr", _, _], Infinity];
```

with

```
rows = Rest @ Cases[tab, XMLElement["tr", _, _], Infinity];
```

After these changes, `xmlTableToDataset` will work with your url and will stop working with Wikipedia. Can we modify it so that it works for both? This is one way to do so with very a few small changes:

```
xmlTableToDataset[tab_] :=
    Module[ {headerRow, headers, data, rows},

        headerRow = FirstCase[ tab[[3]], XMLElement["tr", __], None, Infinity ];

        headers = 
            Cases[ 
                headerRow, 
                d:XMLElement["th" | "td",_ ,_ ] :> StringTrim @ StringJoin @ Flatten @ System`Convert`HTMLImportDump`SymbolicXML2Text[d],
                Infinity 
            ];

        rows = 
            Cases[
                DeleteCases[tab, headerRow, Infinity],
                XMLElement["tr" ,_ ,_ ],
                Infinity
            ];

        data = 
            Map[
                Cases[
                    #,
                    d:XMLElement["td", _, _] :> StringTrim @ StringJoin @ Flatten @ System`Convert`HTMLImportDump`SymbolicXML2Text[d],
                    Infinity
                ] &,
                rows
            ];

        Dataset @ Map[AssociationThread[headers, #] &, Select[data, Length @ # == Length @ headers &]]
    ]
```

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks for helping me understand this.  Seems to be quite general.  Will continue to test on other online tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to scrap tables, here is another alternative:

```
ClearAll[scrapTables, scrapTablesCore];

scrapTables[url_String] := scrapTablesCore[URLRead[url]["Body"]]
scrapTables[path_File] := scrapTablesCore[ReadString[path]]

scrapTablesCore[text_String] := 
 DeleteCases[#, {}, Infinity] &@
  StringCases[text, 
   Shortest[
     RegularExpression@"<[Tt][Aa][Bb][Ll][Ee][.\\s\\S]*?>" ~~ 
      table___ ~~ 
      RegularExpression@"</[Tt][Aa][Bb][Ll][Ee][.\\s\\S]*?>"] :>
    StringCases[table, 
     Shortest[
       RegularExpression@"<[Tt][Rr][.\\s\\S]*?>" ~~ row___ ~~ 
        RegularExpression@"</[Tt][Rr]>"] :>
      StringCases[row, 
       Shortest[
         RegularExpression@"<[Tt][DdHh][.\\s\\S]*?>" ~~ cell___ ~~ 
          RegularExpression@"</[Tt][DdHh]>"] :>
        StringReplace[StringTrim[cell], 
         Shortest[RegularExpression@"</?[.\\s\\S]+?>"] -> ""]]]]
```

### Examples:

The input type is a URL:

```
Dataset /@ 
 scrapTables[
  "http://earthwise.bgs.ac.uk/index.php/OR/14/008_Lithostratigraphical_units_used_by_BGS"]
```

The above code will output 5 datasets.

Or as a File:

```
Dataset /@ scrapTables[File["C:\\file.html"]]
```

If you want to pick the second table:

```
Dataset @ scrapTables[File["C:\\file.html"]][[2]]
```

Notes:

- It does not store tag's information, only the cell content as a string
- Strings in form of tags such as `<i>`,`<div>`,... will be removed from the content (anything wrapped inside `<>`)
- Output is a list of matrices in which each cell type is String
- Use `AssociationThread` and the first row to create a `Dataset` with column
- If you save the `.html` file, you could use the function with `File[...]` as the argument

Remember the page source may be different from what you see. Seeing 2 tables on a page doesn't mean that the page has only 2 tables in its source. As an example, the light blue banner on top of the page of your link is also a table if you check the source.

Comment: A clean and masterful use of regular expressions is always a sight to behold and learn from.
Thank you.  The primary intent of my question was to understand a fully smybolic manipulation of
the imported XMLObject, but your answer showed there are other elegant approaches.  As we both
observe, tables[[1]] lacks headers and consists solely of a single row presenting an anomalous
table.  Thanks again for the insight.